# Gmail DNS Settings - Do I need CNAME and an A Record?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record, gmail, dns-zone

I'm just a little confused...  I'm using Gmail for my mail service, and have followed their instructions.  I wanted to allow users to access their email via mail.mydomain.com, but just hoping to get a little clarification.

Do I need *both* the CNAME and A records, or just the CNAME?

I deleted the A record for mail.mydomain.com and added a CNAME recored which points to ghs.googlehosted.com.  But, now I'm wondering if I should have kept that in there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you were correct to remove the old A record and replace it with the CNAME for ghs.googlehosted.com. If a particular entry (e.g. mail.example.com) has a CNAME record, it should not have either A or AAAA records as these will be disregarded.

Google does not provide individual IP addresses for each customer to use. Setting the CNAME to ghs.googlehosted.com causes requests to go to a specialized server at that address that looks up your domain and redirects web users to Gmail for your domain.

Comment: It CAN have both records, but if CNAME is present, A will be disregarded.

Comment: Email is routed based on MX records, not CNAMEs.

Comment: Doh. I forgot that. And I've even set this up last week.